# Can I override negotiated USB power requirement?

Tags: usb, windows

I have a Wacom CTL-472 tablet. On the back panel it says Input: 5V, 25ma. And if I use a USB power measuring device, it is actually less than that, drawing 19ma.
So I expected to be able to plug this into my (unpowered) USB hub on my keyboard, as that should be able to supply 100ma per port (as per USB standards as I understand them).

However, Windows 10 complains that it is drawing too much power and disables the device.
Huh?

So I used the USBDeview utility with it plugged into a normal powered host port, and it reports that the "Power" is 498ma!  I presume this is what the device requested during USB power negotiation, not the actual usage; i.e. it requested high-power capabilities (not sure why it's 498ma not 500ma in that utility display).

So... am I stuck? I am presuming it's the firmware on the device that is asking for the incorrect power requirements. I'm hoping there might be a way to override that, in Windows registry, or something, where I can say "ignore that power requirement" or "don't worry about that power draw - keep the device connected".

Sorry if this isn't the right forum for this, it may be more of a Windows / software / driver question.

Comment: How do you know that the device will not use 500mA if it requested it? Either it is an error it requests 500mA or it needs up to 500mA at some point during active use.

Comment: Because on the back, it has written that it's max power requirement is 25ma. 
I believe therefore that it is an error, and I want to override it. Even if it burns out my usb port.

Comment: You can complain to manufacturer. Maybe they can release a firmware update which then only requires the minimum possible value of 1 unit of 100mA.

Comment: You might have a better luck asking this question on SuperUser communnity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a clear case of a goofy descriptor setup. It is also a rare case when you have a bus-powered hub that conforms to USB specifications and reports the hub as bus-powered. This triggers the Windows power policy to limit admittance of devices that exceed the 100mA limit (per their descriptor). Most cheap USB hubs lie to Windows and report that they are "self-powered" even if the external power is disconnected. Expensive hubs that are USB-compliant do use some method to sense if the external power is plugged and dynamically change the content of their descriptor  accordingly.

So yes, if you insist on using your lovely keyboard as a connection hub to your tablet, you are stuck, because it is highly unlikely that the tablet manufacturer can make any changes to the max_power field of the device descriptor. It is also highly unlikely that your keyboard can fake the self-power bit in its descriptor.

Unfortunately I am not aware of any backdoor in Windows that allows to ignore the power policy for bus-powered USB hubs, but the idea is interesting. The fact that vast majority of cheap hub manufacturers took the path of ignoring the self-bus-powered requirement tells something about Windows ability/willingness to violate USB specifications.

Comment: Thanks, I found another utility that reports on the hub properties, and the keyboard hub does indeed list itself as bus-powered. So yes, I am stuck :-(

Comment: @mikek, no need to search for utilities, here is the one ultimate USB reporting utility, https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html